# network simulators to simulate a Mail server in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: mail-server

Im looking for a simulator that can simulate a mail server in ubuntu? I would like to see the working of a mail server

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean?

You could, for example, to install Postfix and configure it to work only locally and so it would emulated the server it already is without actually sending or receiving anything outside the local scope you configured it.

Comment: I want to see how the connection is setup..the control messages sent by both the server and client...

Comment: Uhn... Not sure you will find what you want. This seems a little bit theoretical. Maybe a good approach would use a simple mail server and inspect network with another software.
Not exactly my area of expertize ;-)